# How to prevent image from overrunning to previous page in HTML

Tags: python, html, pdfkit

First of all thanks for reading my question and thanks very much to those who present a solution. I'm trying to rotate an image, but it overruns to the previous page after a page break. I want it centered on the current page. Also instead of using rotate image, How does one change a HTML page from portrait to landscape and back again. I would prefer this instead of rotating the image. Below is my current HTML code. Please note that it the template for a python program that produces a pdf file.
The python code is:

```
def CreateReport(fidelityPositions,comparePositions,imagefilename):
    fido_table=pd.DataFrame(fidelityPositions)
    compare_table=pd.DataFrame(comparePositions)
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('c:\\histdata\\'))
    img_string=image_file_path_to_base64_string(imagefilename)
    compare_table=compare_table.round(decimals=4)

    template = env.get_template('myreport10.html')

    template_vars = {"title" : "Portfolio Report",
                 "fidelity_table": fido_table.to_html(),
                 "compare_table": compare_table.to_html(),
                 "img_string": img_string
                     }
    print(compare_table)
    html_out = template.render(template_vars)

    #options = {'enable-local-file-access': None}
    pdfkit.from_string(html_out,"c:\\histdata\\batfiles\\testreport.pdf",configuration=config)#,options=options)
```

The HTML code is: The problem section that bleeds is the HTML code for image 1

```css
.myPage {
  margin: 0.1cm;
  size: landscape;
  orientation: landscape;
}
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.myDiv2 {
  border: 5px outset green;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.myRotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
.center {
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.keep-together {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.break-before {
  page-break-before: always;
}

.break-after {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<div class="returnstable">
  <h2>Returns History</h2>
  {{ fidelity_table }}
  <h2>Compare History</h2>
  {{ compare_table }}
</div>
<div class="break-before">
  this is a test
  <div class="myRotate">
    <div class="myDiv">
      <h2>Historical Returns Image 1</h2>
      <center>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img_string }} " />
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="break-before">
  this is second image
  <div class="myDiv2">
    <h2>Historical Returns Image 2</h2>

    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img_string }} " />
  </div>
</div>
```

The resulting part of the pdf file that shows the page overrun looks like:

[image]